# Can't set android:visibility programmatically for a button using binding?

Tags: android

A class for binding

```
data class MyName (var name: String= "", var nickname: String = "", var showButton: String = "gone")
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
     android:text="@string/toggle"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:visibility="@={myName.showButton}"
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>
```

when I specify the hardcode "gone", `android: visibility=" gone"`, in the XML file, it works fine, but I want to control the visibility of the button programmatically using binding. When I pass "gone" as a binding variable android shows, `****/ data binding error ****msg: Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android: visibility' with value type java.lang.String on android.widget.Button.`

Comment: You can do it normally without binding but programmatically. Have you made any try or you wanna do it by binding?

Comment: I know how to do it using setVisibility(), but I want to know using binding.

Comment: Have you tried **isVisible** instead of **showButton**?

Comment: I got this link after searching on the internet. Have a look, it can be your solution I think. 
Link: https://android--code.blogspot.com/2019/01/android-kotlin-databinding-visibility.html

Comment: Thank you @ShahadatHossain. The link answers my question.

Comment: Welcome :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet from the above link, in the comment section of my question.

change showButton type to Boolean. And import view from the xml in the data tag, to access inside the xml.

```
<data>
    <variable name="myName" type="com.example.aboutme.MyName"/>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>
```

And in the xml file, `android:visibility="@{myName.showButton ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
binding.studentClass = Student("Hasiba Yeasmin",false)
```

> data class Student(val name:String, val isVisible:Boolean)

Link: [Set android: visibility programmatically for a button using binding](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2019/01/android-kotlin-databinding-visibility.html)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, `android:visibility` attribute doesn't support two-way binding as there is no event mechanism to notify when the attribute changes.

Try useing one-way binding:

```
android:visibility="@{myName.showButton}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you cannot use a string  for changing visibility of the value. It takes a special value like `View.VISIBLE`, `View.GONE` and `View.INVISIBLE`.
Try this:

```
data class MyName (var name: String= "", var nickname: String = "", var showButton: Boolean = false)
```

XML:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
    </data>

<Button
     android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
     android:text="@string/toggle"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:visibility="@{myName.showButton? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE }"
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>
</layout>
```